# Problems with external display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, 23.10

My laptop has 2880x1800 display, and my external monitor supports 1920x1080. It is a shitty one indeed, but was working fine with windows. Now, when I swith desktops, only the desktop on the laptop screen changes (the primary display), and the external stays the same, but it crashes. Brave stops responding immediately, and other applications behave strangely. Any suggestions?

And when I set the resolution to the external monior to 1920x1080, system applications look very small, with small font, and for example brave or notion take the whole screen. For the record, Spotify cannot even be expanded because the screen is too small, and when I run btop it says that the dimensions of the screen does nto meet the requirements.

Also, if I open terminal, and switch to another windows excpecially with alt+tab, when I reopen the terminal it is resized in super small dimensions.